# How do I pass string from url and use it to query the list?

Tags: python, django

```
class PatientDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'detail_view.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        vitals_list = DailyVitals.objects.get(patient = )
        context['vitals_list'] = vitals_list
        return context
```

What query should I pass to filter queryset with the patient's username?

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('addRecord/', VitalCreateView.as_view(), name='create_record'),
    path('detail/<str:username>', PatientDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('doctor', DoctorView.as_view(), name='doctor'),
    path('patient', PatientView.as_view(), name='patient'),
]
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField('doctor status', default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField('patient status', default=False)


class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class DailyVitals(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    blood_pressure = models.IntegerField()
    sugar_level = models.IntegerField()
    temperature = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("patient")
```

I tried to pass
<a href= {% url 'detail' i.patient.user.username %}>
from the template but I get this error "

*Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/(?P[^/]+)\Z']:*

Thanks

Comment: Hey, my guess is that your variable i is not set in the template. But can you please post your template code to be sure?

Comment: {% for i in patients_list %}
                        <li><a href= {% url 'detail' i.patient.user.username %}>{{i}}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        <ul>